# Many colours and much colour

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Many colours mean many types of colour, and much colour means a large quantity of colour, is it right?

Colourful - Having much or varied colour

https://www.lexico.com/definition/colourful

Comment: _Many colours_ implies different colours. _Much colour_ isn't very idiomatic; I would expect _bright_ or _strong colour_. How do you intend to use the phrase?

Comment: The only way I can think of "much colour" is in the negative: There isn't much colour on this poster.  (meaning it is mostly black and white)  Was this the sort of example you had in mind?  Can you add an example to your question, please.

Comment: It isn't *wrong* to say "much colour", it's just unusual i.e. not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not normally use "much colour". Having "much colour" would mean it is colourful.  A bright-red coat might be described as colourful, even though it only has one colour.

It is acceptable to use this in the negative: "The coat doesn't have much colour" It would mean it is mostly black, white or grey.  It could mean that the colours are pale.

Dictionary definitions are often not examples of natural English.  This is because the idiomatic way to describe something is to say "It is colourful" But the definition of "colourful" has to find an alternative word or phrase that means the same. That phrase might have to be non-idiomatic.

Comment: You made a half-red half-blue drawing. To make more part of it red, should I say, “more red colour, please”?

Comment: "More red please", using "red" as a noun would be the minimal.  But you should say more "Could you use more red in your drawing because...."